# how to generate xml using single jaxb instance

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I want to generate following xml structure using one jaxb marshaller instance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ABC>//root element
    <BCD>
        <DEF>
            <EFG>xyz</EFG>
            <FGH>
                <GHI>PASSWORD_1</GHI>
                <HIJ>false</HIJ>
            </FGH>
        </DEF>
    </BCD>
    <CDE/>
</ABC>
<ABC>//root element
    <BCD>
        <DEF>
            <EFG>xyz</EFG>
            <FGH>
                <GHI>PASSWORD_2</GHI>
                <HIJ>false</HIJ>
            </FGH>
        </DEF>
    </BCD>
    <CDE/>
</ABC>
<ABC>// root element
    <BCD>
        <DEF>
            <EFG>xyz</EFG>
            <FGH>
                <GHI>PASSWORD_3</GHI>
                <HIJ>false</HIJ>
            </FGH>
        </DEF>
    </BCD>
    <CDE/>
</ABC>
```

I above structure node ABC is root node which I want to repeat in same file for multiple records in list. Is there a way to do so in JaxB?

Comment: you have an `ABC` object, that has a `BCD` object, that has a `DEF` object, that has a field `EFG` and an object `FGH`. This has then two fields, namely `GHI` and `HIJ`

Comment: Yes, ABC is my root element. under that I have that hierarchy and after marshaling I want to repeat that structure of root element ABC but with different value for password but that should be in same xml file

Comment: It seems that JAXB needs an unique root-element. I found no example with multiple root-elements. But also I found no definition that the root element **has really to be unique**. So I think you have just to try it with your example.

Comment: so you have to build your `List<ABC>`, that contains the respective `ABC` objects you want

Comment: I did that by building list of ABC object but it throws following error javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class java.util.ArrayList nor any of its super class is known to this context.

Comment: What happens when you build your hierarchy without `List<>`?

Comment: Then it just overwrites it. you will get last object data in xml

Comment: Then it seems in deed, that you can't do it with JAXB. It requires an unique root-element.

Comment: there may be some way out. not necessary to have standard but solution may be there.

Comment: I done with it. I got the solution though it is not fit in standard programming but helped me to complete my task.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot since this is not valid XML. XML documents must have exactly one root element.

Comment: don't know but some how I managed to do it through non standard programming practice.